# PHP Websockets extension on Microsoft Azure website

Tags: php, azure, websocket

I want to use web sockets on my PHP website hosted on Microsoft Azure.

For this I need to use the websockets extension php_sockets.dll.
I added the php_sockets.dll to my wwwroot/bin folder. I edited the app settings as followed:
[image: screenshot azure app settings]

But I get the following error in de log:
Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\mywebsite\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\bin\php_sockets.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Is Azure blocking it?

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me! Here are some things to keep in mind:

1. Make sure you are downloading the `php_sockets.dll` from the [PHP for Windows](http://windows.php.net/download) site
2. Make sure you download the proper version (for example, I'm running PHP 5.4 on my Azure Website, so I downloaded the PHP 5.4.40 ZIP file form the page listed above).
3. Make sure you download the **VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe** package.
4. As you mentioned in your question, create a folder titled `bin` in the `wwwroot` folder and place the DLL in this folder.
5. Follow the steps in the Azure documentation: [Configure PHP in web apps](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#configure-via-app-setting))