# Azure Web App PHP 7.1 websocket does not work

Tags: php, azure, websocket

I'm trying to deploy PHP code with Websocket in in a Azure Web App environment.
It works fine on a Virtual server but it does not run as a Web App.
I find some older articles that this might not work.

I like to avoid useing Virtual servers, so any insight on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you post any errors you are getting ?

Comment: @Tom-ErikBlix May the existing SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299206/php-websockets-extension-on-microsoft-azure-website will helps to fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry no, this does not solve the issue.. We also have problems with port forwarding and that we should execute it seperatly. So i guess we will create two Web App instances to solve it

Comment: We get 5xx failiures...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to deploy a Docker container image - this was the only way we could find that solved the problem.